# Scrape links, store in array and then run another process in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I currently have two CasperJS scripts that I want to combine into one for usability purposes. test1.js scrapes a webpage for links ( `<a>` elements). All the resulting links scraped are stored in an array `urls`.  Script test2.js takes a `link` and extracts youtube src link if present from iframe.

How can I gather all links (test1.js) and then visit each link to extract a `youtube` link (test2.js), finally store YouTube links in array and display result?

test1.js

```
var urls = [];
var casper = require('casper').create();
function getNumberOfItems(casper) {
    return casper.getElementsInfo(".listview .badge-grid-item").length;
}

function tryAndScroll(casper) {
  casper.page.scrollPosition = { top: casper.page.scrollPosition["top"] + 4000, left: 0 };
  var info = casper.getElementInfo('.badge-post-grid-load-more');
  if (info.visible) {
    var curItems = getNumberOfItems(casper);
    if( curItems <= 60 ) {
        casper.waitFor(function check(){
          return curItems != getNumberOfItems(casper);
        }, function then(){
          tryAndScroll(this);
        }, function onTimeout(){
          this.echo("Timout reached");
        }, 20000);
    }
  } else {
    casper.echo("no more items");
  }

}

casper.start('http://example.com', function() {
     tryAndScroll(this);
});

casper.then(function() {
  casper.each(this.getElementsInfo('.title'), function(casper, element, j) {
    var url = element["attributes"]["href"];
    urls.push(url);
  });
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo(urls.join('\n')).exit();
    this.echo(urls.length + ' links found');
});
```

test2.js (Currently only  takes one url)

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var yt_links = [];

casper.start('http://example.com', function() {
    this.click('.responsivewrapper');
});

casper.then(function() {
  casper.each(this.getElementsInfo('.badge-youtube-player'), function(casper, element, j) {
    var url = element["attributes"]["src"];
    yt_links.push(url);
  });
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo(yt_links.join('\n')).exit();
    this.echo(yt_links.length + ' link(s) found');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start` and `run` functions of CasperJS can only be used once, but there is also the `thenOpen` function to open a URL in a step. All `then*` and `wait*` functions are step functions. By calling them, you essentially schedule the steps that those functions represent. Furthermore, you can nest CasperJS steps. So that the steps further down in the script, but higher up in the tree will only be executed when all the nested steps are finished.

```
// last step of test1.js
casper.then(function() {
  this.getElementsInfo('.title').forEach(function(element) {
    // skip elements that don't have a href attribute...
    if (!element.attributes.href) {
      return;
    }
    // here come the contents of test2.js
    casper.thenOpen(element.attributes.href, function() {
      this.click('.responsivewrapper');
    }).then(function(){
      ...
    }).then(function(){
      this.echo(yt_links.join('\n')).exit();
      this.echo(yt_links.length + ' link(s) found');
    });
  });
});
```

I used the builder/promise pattern to make the code example a little shorter.

Comment: You have been of great help! I am getting this error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'url.toLowerCase')`. Above in the quesiton, check how i put it together based on your solution. is that wrong?

Comment: Where does this come from? I don't see this anywhere in the code.

Comment: I believe it is from `var url = element["attributes"]["href"];`

Comment: Full error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'url.toLowerCase')
  /home/user/casperjs/modules/utils.js:112 in cleanUrl
  /home/user/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1424 in open
  /home/user/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1850 in _step
  /home/user/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1571 in runStep
  /home/user/casperjs/modules/casper.js:399 in checkStep`

Comment: Yes, there is one element that has no href attribute. You can find it by typing `$$(".title:not([href])")` into the console in the developer tools of your browser. I added the appropriate condition to skip that element.

Comment: I see the one element with no href attribute. However it is only showing one youtube link source and not all. This is the code put together [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qhd8zwL/) . Please, If possible Artjom could you show me the full code?

Comment: I have already updated my code with the fix for the error. I'm not going to combine this into a complete script. The instructions are all there and I don't like giving away a complete script. I want that you learn something and not simply copy it. Besides it looks as though you already did a good job at combining the two scripts. I guess the only issue you should be having is which variables should be defined globally (I think all of them and especially `yt_links`).